# Suggestions for improving this Python code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How could I improve my code in python if I use a lot of lines like the following

```
post_title_tag = soup.find("h1", {"id": "post-title"})
if post_title_tag is None:
    return
```

In this function

```
def get_post_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    html_source = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

    post_title_tag = soup.find("h1", {"id": "post-title"})
    if post_title_tag is None:
        return

    description_tag = soup.find("p", class_="description")
    if description_tag is None:
        return

    datetext_span = description_tag.find("span")
    if datetext_span is None:
       return
```

Comment: This belongs in codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to wrap the parent function in a try/except block and use a function that throws an exception for you. Something like this:

```
class NoSuchTagException(Exception): pass

def get_tag(parent, name, *args, **kwargs):
    child = parent.find(name, *args, **kwargs)
    if child is None:
        raise NoSuchTagException(name)
    else:
        return child

def get_post_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    html_source = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSuop(html_source)

    post_title_tag = get_tag(soup, 'h1', {'id': 'post-title'})
    description_tag = get_tag(soup, 'p', class_='description')
    datetext_span = get_tag(description_tag, 'span')
```